# VBA Macros : how to open Excel without warning

Tags: vbscript

I created Macro using VB scripting when I am downloading it from client side and opening I am getting warning [Please check the screen shots of warning here]

[image]

I am new to this Vb script and Macro so please suggest me how to avoid this warning from client side. and tell me any suggestion how I can solve it from server side

Comment: Do you mind sharing your code? You can set the "displayalerts" property of excel application to false to avoid getting such messages while opening excel.

Comment: macros in Excel files are `VBA`, not `VBScript`.  You can't save macros in a `.xlsx` file, it needs to be `.xlsm` instead.  You need to show us the code you are using for us to be able to help any further than this.

Comment: But i want the excel in xlsx format only so... what i have to do for that

Comment: string path =Path.Combine(@"D:\1\2\3\4\2.xlsx");
                byte[] renderedBytes = GetReportFileAsBytes(path);
                String FilePath = @"D:\1\2\3\4\5";
                FilePath = FilePath + "\\" + "Helloworld" + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".xlsx";
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    stream.Write(renderedBytes, 0, renderedBytes.Length);
                    stream.Close();
                    return "file created";
                }

Comment: public byte[] GetReportFileAsBytes(String ReportPath)
        { byte[] ReportFileAs = null; XSSFWorkbook xlWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(Convert.ToString(ReportPath)); xlWorkBook.IsMacroEnabled();
 ISheet sheet = xlWorkBook.GetSheet("Sheet1");
    if (sheet != null)
 sheet.SetActive(true);
 MemoryStream _ExcelFile = null;
            using (_ExcelFile = new MemoryStream())
            {
                xlWorkBook.Write(_ExcelFile);
                _ExcelFile.Close();
            }
            ReportFileAs=_ExcelFile.ToArray();
            return ReportFileAs;
        }

Comment: @Neetha, please edit your original post and insert the code there - it's not possible to read it easily from the comments...

Comment: And if you want the excel file in `.xlsx` format - you can't have a macro in the file.  You could go for the older `.xls` format, but not the `.xlsx` one

Comment: can you tell me briefly once

Comment: Step 1 - Put your code into the original post using the Edit link directly under the question.   Step 2 - adjust the tags on your question to apply to the language you are using (which appears to be `vb.net` rather than either `vba` or `vbscript`). Step 3 - Wait to see what assistance you get now your question is correctly targeted.

Comment: @Dave Actually that code looks more like C# or something - none of the Visual Basic languages use semi-colons to end statements, or braces for blocks of code.  (At least, none of the ones I have seen.)

Comment: @YowE3K Good point, I just knew it wasn't vbscript or vba...